# get one cell of data from database

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-express

i want to get the data from my database.
table name is MsUser that containing userID, username, and password.
there's several row of it.

form description :
i have from login, that need username and password to login.
after login the transaction form opened, and in that form the userId will be displayed using label, userID based on the username that have logged in.

this is the code that i use to match the username and password
sorry if my english was bad.
and thanks so much for your help, really.

```
  private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ProgII Project\MoneyManager\MoneyManager\MsUser.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From MsUser where username='"+txtUsername.Text+"' and password='"+txtPassword.Text+"'",cn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="1")
            {
                this.Hide();

            }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your id or password is wrong");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Side note: use parmeterized queries to prevent from `SQL` injections

Comment: If you get back one row, one column (like for `SELECT COUNT(*)`), use the `SqlCommand` and its `.ExecuteScalar()` method - no need to incur all the overhead of a `DataTable` just for a single value!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i'm a newbe. can you explain what sql injection is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your user table contains one unique record per username-password combination,

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string requiredUserId;

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ProgII Project\MoneyManager\MoneyManager\MsUser.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(userID),UserId From MsUser where username='"+txtUsername.Text+"' and password='"+txtPassword.Text+"' Group By userID",cn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                requiredUserId=dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(); //Use this requiredUserId in your next form!!
            }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your id or password is wrong");
        }

    }
```

Comment: and of course its a good practice to use parametrized queries as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27794391/2313371

Answer (score 3):

If you get back exactly one row, one column (like for `SELECT COUNT(*)`), use the SqlCommand and its .ExecuteScalar() method - no need to incur all the overhead of a DataTable just for a single value!

Use something like this:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // define query - and **ALWAYS** use parameters!
    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.MsUser WHERE username = @UserName AND password = @password);";

    // set up connection and command
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ProgII Project\MoneyManager\MoneyManager\MsUser.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        // define parameters and provide values
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtUserName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtPassword.Text;

        // open connection, execute command, close connection
        cn.Open();
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cn.Close();

        // if result is not null and can be converted to an int....
        if(result != null)
        {
            int userCount;

            if(int.TryParse(result.ToString(), out userCount))
            {
                // OK, you have a good value - if it's > 0, your user entry exists....
                if (userCount > 0)
                {
                    // success - user exists with password
                }
                else 
                {
                    // no success - no such entry
                }
            }
            else
            {
               // you didn't get a numeric value......
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // you didn't get any value......
        }
    }
}
```

Also: please make sure you ***NEVER EVER*** store a password in **plain text** in your database table !!

**Update:** if you need to retrieve the `UserId` (instead of just the count), use a query like this:

```
string query = "SELECT UserId FROM dbo.MsUser WHERE username = @UserName AND password = @password);";
```

and then check if you got back a valid `UserId` (not sure what datatype that might be....)

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

// checking if we got something (or null)
if (result != null)
{
    string userId = result.ToString();
}
else
{
     // we didn't get any "UserId" back -> invalid combination of "username" and "password"
}
```

Comment: from what i can say ... "and in that form the userId will be displayed using label, userID based on the username that have logged in. " ... sounds like he wants to show the id but does not know how to change the existing code ...

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, but be aware of [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
**Updated** code to prevent Sql Injection.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\ProgII Project\MoneyManager\MoneyManager\MsUser.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From MsUser where username = @username and password = @passowrd", cn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", idBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passowrd", passwordBox.Text.Trim());            

        int returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

        if (returnValue == 1)
        {
             this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your id or password is wrong");
        }
 }
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thankyou for your knowledge, really.